# How to start new activity intent to overlay camera surfaceview on mainactivity

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to know how to change activity intents while preserving the camera preview as the background of my application.

Currently, Im using addView() to overlay my xml layouts(inflated) on top of the camera SurfaceView on MainActivity and overriding the onBackPressed() and populating it with removeViewAt() and addView() to move back in my views.

I think my current code is really messy because I am only using one class (MainActivity class) to switch through my views.

I want to use Intents because I think my code would be more organized and so that I will not have problems overriding the onBackPressed() because each activity would be "back stacked".

Comment: I know this is not an answer, but can help you with some guidance, I have started a project that use a custom view to use the cellphone camera, try to take a look at  the classes PlayerSelectionActivity and CameraActivity https://github.com/lpbaptista/Party-Monsters , if you need more help just send a msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay.. I have been reading and found out that the best approach to do this is by using Fragments. And that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To enable your camera to be running throughout the application, try to have a CameraPreview.java class, and simply call this in every activity you want to have camera running.

```
private Camera mCamera = null;
private CameraPreview mPreview;
SurfaceView surfaceView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.cameralayout);
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, surfaceView);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();  
    mCamera = CameraPreview.getCameraInstance();
    mPreview.setCamera(mCamera);    
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mPreview.setCamera(null);
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null; 
    }
}
```

On the other hand, you can try setting flags while switching activities to clear stack

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: ill give it a try. ill post the result later

Comment: what is the code inside getCameraInstance() and setCamera()?

Comment: Will this code restart the camera in every activity? Because I would prefer that the camera would not reload while changing activities

Comment: yea, this code is meant to release resources used by the camera. getCameraInstance() is where I call Camera.open() and setCamera() is used for mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder)